# Simultaneous equations using distances in polar coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, polar-coordinates

Working on a project and this problem came up.

Trying to find a general form for $r_q$ and $\theta _q$ from these two simultanous equations. I'm think that there will be many cases (almost all of them) where a solution doesn't exist but I am hoping that there will still be a general form that will just have undefined or complex results.

The first is $L_a = \sqrt{r_a^2 + r_q^2 - 2r_ar_q\cos(\theta_a - \theta_q)}$ 
The second is $L_b = \sqrt{r_b^2 + r_q^2 - 2r_br_q\cos(\theta_b - \theta_q)}$

I have tried to solve this on my own but its been years since I've done any maths and I unfortunately can't take the time to relearn all I've forgotten to figure this out.

What I am trying to do is find the points where a point $Q$ is a set distance, $L_a$, from a known point $A$ and a set distance, $L_b$, away from another known point $B$.

I got these equations by looking for an equation for the distance between two points using Polar coordinates. The problem is that I need this to work inside a piece of software I am writing so I can't just plug in the numbers and solve it manually every time which is why I was hoping for a way of finding $r_q$ and $\theta_q$ in general forms that I can then use within the software.

Also in terms of what I've tried to do I didn't try to use any of the advanced techniques I was taught back when I was a maths student as I haven't looked at any of them in years so I spent about half an hour trying to combine them or rearrange them with basic algebra before giving up and coming here.

N.B. I am not trying to use this in any kind of commercial software it is for a personal project for a tabletop game.

Comment: How do you want to get help if you do not explain what you already tried and where you are stuck with this problem ? Please, edit your question.

Comment: 1) Your expressions aren't homogeneous: you need squaring $r_a +r_q \to r_a^2+r_q^2$ etc... 2) Besides: **your issue isn't understandable:** As it has a geometric origin, you have to explain the context : "I have these triangles with these lengths, etc." **with a figure**

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici okay, I have edited the question to try and add more context. hopefully that is helpful

Comment: @JeanMarie I have edited the question to add context however I haven't added any kind of diagram as frankly I wouldn't know how to create anything to describe the situation that would be of any help

Comment: You need a figure, ! I am still unable to understand what $r_q$ is for.. Is it the distance MQ where $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$ ?

Comment: No answer to my last question ?

Comment: @JeanMarie $r_q$ is the first part of the polar coordinate of the point Q. so it is the distance between the point Q and the origin. and $\theta_q$ is angle between the positive x axis and the point Q. I didn't think that needed explaining as I thought using r and theta to describe those points was standard practise as that is what I was taught when I was studying polar coordinates

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. A remark:  your equations are valid only is origin O is not anywhere but on line [AB]. **Had you drawn a figure**,  we wouldn't have had this discussion... This said, I advise you to take $O$ as the midpoint of line segment AB ; in this way, you fall into a classical system called **two center bipolar coordinates** for which you will find formulas [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-center_bipolar_coordinates) !

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't understand why the equations are only valid if [AB] passes through the origin. The equations were listed as the distance between any two points on a polar plane. I'm essentially drawing circles around two polar points and then solving for the intersection of those circles. I still don't understand why the origin has anything to do with it

Comment: Have you seen 1) My new comment 2) And in particular how simple are the formulas for two center bipolar coordinates. I advise you to use them.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have looked at your link and I cannot work out how any of those formulas fit what I am trying to do and there is no explanations or anything understandable there. This is to solve a problem inside a piece of software which manages a bunch of points described as polar coordinates and the origin won't be between A and B, and finding the distance from the midpoint of [AB] to the point Q doesn't help find the actual polar coordinates of Q.

Comment: It will be through a change of coordinates.

Comment: @JeanMarie I need you to understand that I am not a mathmatician and even asking the question was already pushing the limits of my understanding so "a change of coordinates" is almost meaningless to me unfortunately. If you can come up with a solution then please add it as an answer to my question otherwise I think this conversation is wasting both of our time as I just can't understand what you are trying to explain to me.

Comment: All right. I have understood. I will try to give you formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Finding point $Q$ at given distances $L_a,L_b$ from 2 fixed points $A(x_A,y_A), B(x_B,y_B)$ resp. is like finding the intersecting points of the circles with centers $A$ and $B$ and radii $L_a,L_b$ resp.

[image]

Please note that I refer to cartesian coordinates with:

$$x_A=r_a \cos \theta_a, y_A=r_a \sin \theta_a, etc.$$

Therefore, we have to solve, i.e., find solution(s) $(x,y)$ (which will be the cartesian coordinates of $Q_k$) to the system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}(x-x_A)^2+(y-y_A)^2&=&L_a^2 & \ \ Eq.(1) \ \text{of the first circle}\\
(x-x_B)^2+(y-y_B)^2&=&L_b^2 & \ \ Eq.(2) \ \text{of the 2nd circle}
\end{cases}$$

which is equivalent to the system where (Eq. 1) is kept as it is and (Eq. 2) is replaced by the equation obtained as the difference between Eq. (1) and Eq. (2) (this is in fact the equation of line $Q_1Q_2$, called the "radical axis" of the 2 circles):

$$\begin{cases}(x-x_A)^2+(y-y_A)^2&=&L_a^2 & \ \ Eq.(1)\\
2(x_A-x_B)x+2(y_A-y_B)y+\underbrace{(x_B^2+y_B^2)}_{r_B^2}-\underbrace{(x_A^2+y_A^2)}_{r_A^2}&=&L_b^2 -L_a^2& \ \ Eq.(2')\\
\end{cases}$$

Extracting $y$ from Eq. (2') will give you a first degree expression in variable $x$, say

$$y=ux+v \tag{3}$$

that you will plug into  into Eq. (1), getting in this way a quadratic equation in $x$ that will give you 2 solutions $x_1,x_2$. Plugging each one in (3), you will get the associated $y_1,y_2$. In this way the two  possible points are $Q_1(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q_2(x_2,y_2).$

It will remain to switch back, if necessary, to polar coordinates

Comment: Have you been able to exploit the method and reach formulas for values $(x_k,y_k)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

@Jean Marie's approach and answer expliaan very clearly why solutions may not exist (as you mentioned in the post).

Solving the problem as you set it is quite simple. Start squaring to get
$$L^2_a =r_a^2 + r_q^2 - 2r_ar_q\cos(\theta_a - \theta_q)\tag 1$$
$$L^2_b =r_b^2 + r_q^2 - 2r_br_q\cos(\theta_b - \theta_q)\tag 2$$
Subtract one from the other and solve for $r_q$; assuming that
$$r_a\cos(\theta_a - \theta_q)  -r_b\cos(\theta_b - \theta_q)\neq 0$$
$$r_q=\frac 12 \frac{ (L^2_b -r_b^2)-(L^2_a -r_a^2)} {r_a\cos(\theta_a - \theta_q)  -r_b\cos(\theta_b - \theta_q)}\tag3$$ Plug this in $(1)$ and expand the cosine to get  simple expression in $\cos(\theta_q)$; solve it for $\theta_q$ and go back to $(3)$ to get $r_q$.

@Jean-Marie's solution is so simpler that it is not worth continuing !!

Comment: I should have seen this way, permitting to remain with simple calculations within a polar coordinates system ! Have a good week end!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to finish this for me? Even though the other solution may be simplier this seems more suitable to implimented within the code